# How can I copy object keyframes to a bone?

Tags: animation, objects, bones, keyframes

Here is a video that I made for better understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zIEXf2Enzw

If I try doing this in the dope sheet action editor then my bone keyframe works correctly but the problem is that those keyframes attached to the object mode not to the pose mode. I tried using the F curve editor with ctrl c and ctrl v keyframes but then my bone is messed up.

Comment: Just add a copy transforms constraint to the bone, copying the objects transforms. Then bake the action of the bone.

Comment: I tried it and messed up the movement this too.  Here is a blend file, you can try it: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/0/b/b/0bb6a7a0e3690471f7eb1576428d7bea8c958dbb.blend

Comment: Works fine, remember to apply the constraint to the **bone** not the armature, and when baking enable **Visual Keying**, **Clear Constraints**, **Pose** and optionally *overwrite current action*

Comment: Well it seems to working for me now, last time I deleted the transform constraint after apply as rest pose, it broke the anim. Is there a way to apply the consraint ?

Comment: No, baking it is applying it.

Comment: Well it is working for now :D I forgot to check the visual keying at the last try. Before that I didn't know about this bake option. Thank you very much !